# Xcode is expecting Void in Boolean function and throws error

Tags: swift

I am trying to do `shouldPerformSegue` function however I am getting error:

> Unexpected non-void return value in void function

Why I am getting error like this? The function is not Void in any way and should expect boolean as return type.

```
override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String?, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        if let phoneNumber = phoneNumberTextField.text{
            if let ident = identifier{
                if ident == "pincode"{
                    API.sendVerificationCode(phoneNumber: phoneNumber){ (error, success) in
                        if error != nil{
                            return false // error is here
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
            return true
    }
```

What should I do? Am I stupid or is Xcode buggy?

Comment: Is your `return false` in a closure? If so I think you are returning from the closure instead of the method.

Comment: You can have multiple `let` bindings in single if statement, you know...

Comment: the return in the function is in other scope different from the one you are calling the API call in...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's because you're returning within the scope of the closure, not within the scope of your function. Try this:

```
override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String?, sender: Any?) -> Bool {

    var shouldPerform = true

    if let phoneNumber = phoneNumberTextField.text{
        if let ident = identifier{
            if ident == "pincode"{
                API.sendVerificationCode(phoneNumber: phoneNumber){ (error, success) in
                    if error != nil{
                        shouldPerform = false
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return shouldPerform
}
```

This assumes that API.sendVerificationCode is synchronous. If it's asynchronous then you'll need to rethink your entire approach.

Comment: This won't work either. The method will always return `true`.

Comment: Then it does not work. You need an (asynchronous) completion handler which is useless in this case. You need to redesign your workflow.

Comment: This answer is not correct and should not be accepted. It fixes the compiler error but will not work properly at runtime as stated by vadian.

Comment: The answer fixes the problem given by the poster. The fact that the closure is asynchronous and not synchronous is a separate problem that the poster should raise in a separate question.

Comment: This answer is wrong because the API call is asynchronous and the function returns the value before the API result is processed to that value

Comment: That wasn't the question. As much fun as this discussion is, this is my last comment on the subject.